# How to change PageViewController dots position in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uipageviewcontroller

[image]

How you can see my imageView doesn't cover full screen. How can I do that my imageView will cover full screen and dots was on imageView?

I did it with viewController + PageViewController.

I resize it with:

```
self.pageViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.width, self.view.frame.size.height)
```

My code is long, so if you want to see exact part of my code - just ask about it

Comment: What is the size of your image? Is it big enough?

Comment: @Munahil yes, of course

Comment: Make a UIImageView the size you want, and set image in it as "Scale to Fill", instead of Aspect Fit

Answer (score 0):

If you have to show only images in your array, then you can use UIScrollView to contain all images.

After that you can use UIPageControl. Add UIPageControl to your UIView.

Then in ScrollViewDidEndDecelerating method, by computing contentOffset of UIScrollView you can set UIPageControl.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the pageVC delegate to know when the page was changed and update the dots.